# Accumulating row values c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am looking to accumulate the value of each cell and display this in a "total column" at the end of the grid in flex cell. Which is the best way of going about this?

I have following code so far which I don't think is correct!

```
int total = 0;
for (int B = 3; B < 27; B++)
{
    total = total + int.Parse(this.grid2.Cell(0, B).ToString());
    this.grid2.Cell(0, 27).Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Well, there are a few too many "magic values" for my taste (what is `27`? why start at `3`?), but for summing up stuff a loop over all values and `total += value` is a very good way of doing it. But put `this.grid2.Cell(0, 27).Text = total.ToString();` outside of the `for` loop! No need to write out the total every time. Just write it after you really have it. Also `int.Parse(this.grid2.Cell(0, B).ToString())` looks very ugly. What is the type of `this.grid2.Cell(0, B)`?

Comment: i want to start the sum in cell 3 and finish the sum in cell 27

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me, but it can be improved:

```
int total = 0;
for (int B = 3; B < 27; B++)
{
      total = total + Convert.ToInt32(this.grid2.Cell(0, B));
}

this.grid2.Cell(0, 27).Text = total.ToString();
```

Only put things that need to be repeated inside the for-loop. If it only needs to be done once, put it after (or before if possible) the loop.
Also, try to use more meaningfull names for your variables. I would change 'B' to either 'i' if you don't want to give it a long name, or to 'column', so you (and other developers, like us) know what it stands for.

BTW, the code calculates the sum for one row (the first one). If you want to do it for every row, then you will need a double for-loop:

```
for(int row = 0;row < numRows; row++){
  int total = 0;
    for (int column = 3; column < 27; column++)
    {
          total = total + Convert.ToInt32(this.grid2.Cell(row, column));
    }
  this.grid2.Cell(row, 27).Text = total.ToString();
}
```